T-SQL Pivot using different aggregate FOR value columns
I need to put on columns the date and amount for first 6 items of type 'R' and first 3 items of any other type. Columns starting with letter "a" are pivoted from a different aggregation column. I managed to do it as per below code but is there any easier and optimal way?
My code queries the source table for each column that needs to be pivoted, this is two times.
CREATE TABLE #TmpChgs 
(
    dPer VarChar(25),
    dAmnt Money,
    sFlag VarChar(20)   
)

INSERT INTO #TmpChgs
    SELECT '2408.Aug-24',0, 'R'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2407.Jul-24',188, 'R'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2401.Jan-24',250, 'R'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2406.Jun-24',325, 'R'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2405.May-24',118, 'R'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2404.Apr-24',0, 'R'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2403.Mar-24',0, 'R'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2402.Feb-24',175, 'R'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2312.Dec-23',0, 'R'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2311.Nov-22',480, 'R'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2310.Oct-23',114, 'R'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2408.Aug-24',0, 'M'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2407.Jul-24',188, 'M'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2401.Jan-24',250, 'M'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2406.Jun-24',325, 'C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2405.May-24',118, 'C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2404.Apr-24',0, 'M'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2403.Mar-24',0, 'C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2402.Feb-24',175, 'M'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2312.Dec-23',0, 'C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2311.Nov-22',480, 'C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2310.Oct-23',114, 'C'

/* Select top 6 R items non 0 order by period and top 3 M or C items non 0 of second type*/
SELECT
    ISNULL(dt.sType, a.sType) rtype, 
    R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6,
    aR1, aR2, aR3, aR4, aR5, aR6,
    O1, O2, O3, aO1, aO2, aO3
FROM
    (SELECT
         sFlag AS sType,
         [R1], [R2], [R3], [R4], [R5], [R6],
         [O1], [O2], [O3]
     FROM 
         (SELECT
              CASE 
                  WHEN sFlag = 'R' 
                      THEN 'R' ELSE 'O' END + 
                           CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sFlag ORDER BY dPer DESC) AS VarChar(10)) AS sPer,
              dPer, sFlag
          FROM
              #TmpChgs
          WHERE
              dAmnt > 0) AS pdt
     PIVOT
         (MAX(dPer) 
             FOR sPer IN ([R1], [R2], [R3], [R4], [R5], [R6],
                          [O1], [O2], [O3])) AS dtPvt
) AS dt
Full Outer Join
(Select sFlag As sType
       ,[aR1],[aR2],[aR3],[aR4],[aR5],[aR6],[aO1],[aO2],[aO3]
FROM (
       Select Case When sFlag='R' Then 'aR' Else 'aO' End + Cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By sFlag Order By dPer desc) as VarChar(10))  As sPer
              ,dAmnt 
              ,sFlag
       From  #TmpChgs
       Where dAmnt>0
      ) As pdt
PIVOT
( Sum(dAmnt) FOR sPer IN ([aR1],[aR2],[aR3],[aR4],[aR5],[aR6],[aO1],[aO2],[aO3])
) as aPvt
) as A On dt.sType=A.sType

The result looks fine but I am worried on the performance when this query will run against table with large date volume.



rtype
R1
R2
R3
R4
R5
R6
aR1
aR2
aR3
aR4
aR5
aR6
O1
O2
O3
aO1
aO2
aO3




C
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
2406.Jun-24
2405.May-24
2311.Nov-22
325.00
118.00
480.00


M
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
2407.Jul-24
2402.Feb-24
2401.Jan-24
188.00
175.00
250.00


R
2407.Jul-24
2406.Jun-24
2405.May-24
2402.Feb-24
2401.Jan-24
2311.Nov-22
188.00
325.00
118.00
175.00
250.00
480.00
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL





Is '2408.Aug-24' a date? This might not sort as expected.

you can use conditional case expression to perform the required pivoting.
with cte as
(
  Select sFlag,
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By sFlag Order By dPer desc),
         dPer,
         dAmnt
  From  #TmpChgs
  Where dAmnt > 0
)
select rtype = sFlag,
       R1    = max(case when sFlag =  'R' and rn = 1 then dPer end),
       R2    = max(case when sFlag =  'R' and rn = 2 then dPer end),
       R3    = max(case when sFlag =  'R' and rn = 3 then dPer end),
       R4    = max(case when sFlag =  'R' and rn = 4 then dPer end),
       R5    = max(case when sFlag =  'R' and rn = 5 then dPer end),
       R6    = max(case when sFlag =  'R' and rn = 6 then dPer end),
       aR1   = max(case when sFlag =  'R' and rn = 1 then dAmnt end),
       aR2   = max(case when sFlag =  'R' and rn = 2 then dAmnt end),
       aR3   = max(case when sFlag =  'R' and rn = 3 then dAmnt end),
       aR4   = max(case when sFlag =  'R' and rn = 4 then dAmnt end),
       aR5   = max(case when sFlag =  'R' and rn = 5 then dAmnt end),
       aR6   = max(case when sFlag =  'R' and rn = 6 then dAmnt end),
       O1    = max(case when sFlag <> 'R' and rn = 1 then dPer end),
       O2    = max(case when sFlag <> 'R' and rn = 2 then dPer end),
       O3    = max(case when sFlag <> 'R' and rn = 3 then dPer end),  
       aO1   = max(case when sFlag <> 'R' and rn = 1 then dAmnt end),
       aO2   = max(case when sFlag <> 'R' and rn = 2 then dAmnt end),
       aO3   = max(case when sFlag <> 'R' and rn = 3 then dAmnt end)
from   cte
group by sFlag


For those interested, here is a fiddle showing both queries and their execution plans.
